# How OAuth authorization works via API

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0

It is clear how to get a token from Google(or any other OAuth provider). But I do not understand where shoud I do it - server part or client part.

For example: I have a backend on Flask with unified API for Android, iOS and web(js/react) apps.
Where do I need to get a token? On the client (Android for example) part and send it to server or in my Flask app after request from client? Where should I get data from provider? How at all works interaction between client and server while using OAuth?

Would be pleased for some explanations or links on some guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIs will manage redirecting the user to authenticate - after which the UI is given an access token to call the API with.

The OAuth provider is the entry point for authentication and issues an access token afterwards.

The API uses the access token to identify the user and authorize access to resources.

A good way to understand OAuth is the HTTP messages - my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) highlights these, and they are largely the same for SPAs and mobile.

There are also some code samples on my blog which you can run, in case useful.